# Pytube output path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I have a problem with pytube output path, when i set output_path to C:/Users/%UserProfile%/Desktop videos stopped downloading, what is wrong with code?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import re
from pytube import YouTube
sg.theme('Dark')

layout = [
            [sg.Text('Enter Youtube video link'), sg.InputText()],
            [sg.Button('Download'), sg.Button('Cancel')]]
# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Youtube Downloader', layout)
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    if re.search(r'\byoutube.com\b', values[0]) or re.search(r'\byoutu.be\b', values[0]):
        video = YouTube(values[0])
        YouTube(values[0]).streams.filter(res="1080p").first().download(output_path="C:/Users/%UserProfile%/Desktop")
        sg.popup('You downloaded: ', video.title)
    else:
        sg.popup('This is not a Youtube link, please try again  ')
window.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is interpreted as a literal. It does not change. `%UserProfile%` - which would be an environment variable on cmd - is not interpreted (as you probably guessed it would be).

The solution is to use `os.environ` or `os.getenv` (you have to `import os` module) which keeps all the variables in the current environment:

```
output_path=f"{os.environ['UserProfile']}/Desktop"
```

Also, `os.environ['UserProfile']` returns the full path to the user directory, so no need to prefix with  `C:/Users/`.